# Android Material Button with Icon on top of Text

Tags: android, kotlin, android-button, material-components-android, materialbutton

Is it possible to have a material button with an icon on top of its text as such:

[image: Buttons]

If yes, can you please explain how with some code?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use linear layout with veritcal orientation having 2 childs : 1st Imageview, 2nd TextView. and can use onClick events on linear layout

Comment: You can use a drawableTop in your layout and give whatever icon you want.If its a textView it will be more easy.If it's a button then you will have to provide a transparent background

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Now you can use the attribute **`iconGravity="top"`**.

Something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    app:icon="@drawable/...."
    app:iconGravity="top" />
```

[image]

**Note:** It requires at least the version **`1.3.0-alpha02`**.

Comment: it does not work for me. == >  AAPT: error: 'top' is incompatible with attribute iconGravity (attr) flags [end=3, start=1, textEnd=4, textStart=2] [weak].

Comment: @Mohammad7G Are you using the version 1.3.0? Here the 1.3.0-rc01 and the value exist: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.3.0-rc01/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/res/values/attrs.xml#L66

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Button attribute "drawableTop" to get the look you are looking for.

```
android:drawableTop="@drawable/YOUR_DRAWABLE_RESOURCE_NAME"
```

Below is a sample code on where it is applied:

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/your_text_view"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Image"
     android:drawableTop="@drawable/YOUR_DRAWABLE_RESOURCE_NAME"/>
```